# Pass URL parameter to href using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

I've got some JavaScript to retrieve a URL parameter, check if the parameter called "pc" was found and if it's value is "tmgppc5" or "tmgggr1", then append to all hrefs on the page.

```
var pc = getQueryVariable("pc"),
url = 'http://www.thisurl.com';

// Check if the parameter called "pc" was found and if it's value is "tmgppc5" or "tmgggr1"
if (pc && pc === "tmgppc5" || "tmgggr1") {
    url += "pc=" + pc; 
}

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('href')[0];
elements.setAttribute('href',url);
```

I'm using getElementsByTagName to search for all hrefs, however I get the error: **uncaught type error cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined**

Using getElementsById on a single href works, using getElementsByClassName returns the same error. What's the cause of the error? Is there an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('href')[0]. Probably, there's simply no element with "href" (<href>) name on the page.

Comment: You may want to swithc to some JS library lik jQuery , lot simpler. `$('a').first().attr('href',url)`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors there, 1. you are searching for "href" instead of "a" and secondly 
you can not setAttribute on node collection, try to loop trough them :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
// You can also use document.querySelectorAll("a")
for (var i=0; i< elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].setAttribute('href',url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag is a for example (a link `<a href=""></a>`), if the links are anchors you could use 
`getElementsByTagName('a')`